# If my double cream/thick cream is about to go bad, can I use it in banoffee pie where no heat will be used for the cream?

Tags: cream

Will the whole pie go bad? I assume it would!

The cream is 1 day past expiry and has sat unopened in the refrigerator and here in the UK, it tends to go bad. It hasn’t quite yet, but it will tomorrow.

I need to use it today. Anyone have any idea on what I can make with 300 mL of thick cream? I just moved and don’t have a mixer, so that rules out so many options.

Comment: @rumtscho, that's not the right duplicate for this question, the OP is talking about NOT heating the cream.  I'm pretty sure there's a different duplicate somewhere, though.

Comment: Ava, I don't think we can help you with this question.  You're asking one question you already know the answer to (will the cream still spoil if I mix it in a pie), and a second question that's not a kind we can accept (what can I do with cream).

Comment: @FuzzyChef I tend to understand the duplicate original as more general. Is there *anything* to turn unsafe food to safe? No, there isn't. Not with heating, not without heating. I searched a bit for a more specific one on expired dairy, but couldn't find any, maybe somebody else will have more luck.

Comment: I'm surprised you say double cream usually goes bad quickly for you – I'm also in the UK and I find it usually lasts weeks past the date

Comment: @rumtscho well, if you, like the OP, had dairy that was about to go off but hadn't yet, you could turn it into cheese or yogurt.    That's not what they're asking about, but it is why those foods exist.  You could also freeze it.  Regardless, this specific question isn't answerable, just wanna get the right close reason for posterity.